# Which is the fastest way to upload the excelsheet having more than 100,000 lines of code in C#?

Tags: c#, database, excel

I want to upload the Excel sheet having more than 100000 rows of data into a SQL server database using C# code.

The Excel spreadsheet contains 20 columns. 
The data needs to get inserted into the 1 master table & 4 other subtables.
I am using the OLEDB Data Provider. I am reading the Excel spreadsheet records into 5 Datatables & then I am inserting it into the SQL Tables.

It is taking too much time to upload the Excel spreadsheet.  When I tried to upload the Excel spreadsheet a second time, it appends the data into the Database. 
The large amount of data insertions & validations of data against the already present data in database is causing the application to stop.

Comment: How big is the file?  Also, I would take my personal email down if I were you.

Comment: Could you clarify if the amount of lines is 100,000 or 1,000,000. In your title you have a typo "1,00,000" and in your question, you state 100,000.

Comment: What you say uploading, what do you mean exactly? Uploading from the client to the web server?

Comment: What kind of database are you inserting into? SQL Server? What version? 2008?

Comment: Also, there's no such thing as "C#.NET". The language is called "C#".

Comment: I would suggest you to have a look at Sql server SSIS. that can do it faster.

Comment: Excel 2007/2010 format or earlier?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using SSIS, which is designed for bulk data transfers like this.  This article outlines how to use it:

**Part 1 - Creating the SSIS package**

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article786-how-to-execute-ssis-packages-in-csharp-aspnet-part-i-.aspx

**Part 2 - Executing the SSIS package from C# code**

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article795-how-to-execute-ssis-packages-in-csharp-aspnet-part-ii-.aspx