# Is SSIS packages are best solution for importing and exporting the large amount of data?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

my requirement is that in nop commerce 1.9  i have to insert multiple discount form a excel sheet which have lot of data so before doing this task i need to be clear in mind which one is best solution for this.

[Which is the fastest way to upload the excelsheet having more than 100,000 lines of code in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517229/which-is-the-fastest-way-to-upload-the-excelsheet-having-more-than-100-000-lines)

i read this question and answer found that `SSIS` is an option .

is really `SSIS` is best for large size file import and export options. 
and what other benefits i will get if i use `SSIS` packages ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For ~100,000 rows, performance should not be a significant problem with this type of data.
SSIS can do this, but it is not the only option.  I think there are three reasonable approaches to doing this:

**SSIS:**
This can read excel files.  If your spreadsheet is well behaved (i.e. can be trusted 
to be laid out correctly) then SSIS can load the contents.  It has some error logging 
features, but in practice it can only usefully dump a log file or write errors out to 
a log table.  Erroneous rows can be directed to a holding table.

**Pros**

- Load process is fairly easy to develop.
- SSIS package can be changed independently of the application if the spreadsheet format has to change.
- Can read directly from spreadsheet file

**Cons:**

- Dependency on having SSIS runtime installed on the system.
- SSIS is really intended to be a server-side installation; error handling tends to consist of writing messages to logs.  You would need to find a way to make error logs available to the user to troubleshoot errors.

**BCP or BULK INSERT:**
You can export the spreadsheet to a CSV and use BCP or a `BULK INSERT` statement to load the file.  However, this requires the file to be exported to a CSV and copied to a drive on the database server or a share accessible to it.

**Pros:**

- Fast
- bcp can be assumed to be present on the server.

**Cons:**

- Requires manual steps to export to CSV
- The file must be placed on a volume that can be mounted on the server
- Limited error handling facilities.

**SqlBulkCopy API:**
If you're already using .Net you can read from the spreadsheet using OLE automation or ODBC and load the data using the SQL Server Bulk Load API.  This requires you to write a C# routine to do the import.   If the spreadsheet is loaded manually then it can be loaded from the user's PC.

**Pros**

- Does not require SSIS to be installed on the computer,
- file can be located on user's PC
- Load process can be interactive, presenting errors to the user and allowing them to correct the errors with multiple retries.

**Cons:**

- Most effort to develop.
- Really only practical as a feature on an application.

Answer (score 2):

SSIS is a ETL tool. You can do transformations, error handling (as mentioned by Kumar), look-ups in the SSIS, you can redirect invalid rows, add derived columns and lot more. You can even add configuration files to it to change some of the properties/parameters ...

There are more options how to load the data to SQL.
1, SSIS - you need to design the workflow (you need BIDS or VS to design and test the package)
2, as "demas" mentioned, you can export the data to flat file and use BCP/bulk insert
3, you can use the openrowset operator on SQL (ad-hoc distributed queries must be enabled to use this functionality) Then you can just query the excel file from SQL - this could be the easy way how to read the data:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0','Excel 8.0;Database=C:\test.xls', 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]') 

- try to look on google for OPENROWSET + EXCEL to get more examples. In this scenario you can query also text files, ACCESS ...
```

There are more ways how to do it, but it really depends on what you want to achieve. 100K rows is really not much in this case.

Answer (score 1):

SSIS is a good solution, but if the performance is most important for you I'll try to convert excel file to plain text file and use [BULK INSERT functionality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188365.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Error logging - Invalid rows can be easily logged into a seperate table for further verification.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to perform complex transformations and required value checking and the file is extremely large (100,000 rows in an Excel file is tiny), the SSIS may be the best solution. It is a very powerful, complex tool.

However, and it is a big however, SSIS is difficult to effectivly learn and work in and is hard to debug. I perform imports and exports as my full-time job and it took me well over a year to get comfortable with SSIS. (of course what I do with the data is very complicated and not at all straightforward, so take this with a grain of salt.) Now if you aren't doing any complex transformations, it isn't that bad to set up, but it is nowhere near as simple as DTS was for instance mostly because it has so much more available functionality. If you are doing simple imports with no transformations, I believe that other methods might be more effective.

As far as performance, SSIS can shine (it is built to move millions or more records to data warehouses where speed is criticial)or be a real dog depending on the way it is set up. It takes a good level of skill to get to where you can performance tune one of these packages.

Comment: I am trying to dump database from oracle,mysql and excel in to my sql server from website which is in asp.net mvc so i want to do this process from website i.e through code.so can you please suggest me something??